# How can i have customized SPA login page in Identity Server (duende identityserver)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I'm looking for a way to have a customized SPA (react/angular) login page beside of my Duende Identity Server API (developed in ASP.NET 6.0)

I googled it all day and just i found this article:

https://medium.com/@piotrkarpaa/using-spa-react-angular-ui-with-identity-server-4-dc1f57e90b2c

Which is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I ran into same situation few days ago, and it was sorted out in a tricky way. And also I landed on this same article you mentioned.
Duende IdentityServer comes with .cshtml pages. The frontend developer designed the same login page (as of reactjs frontend) in .cshtml and inserted that in IdentityServer's login page. Afterwards the workaround was. When user lands on reactjs login page. It automatically redirects to IdentityServer's login page. Though it is not the best approach but a work around that solved our problem.
Background;

- Microservices project
- .net 6 api (backend)
- reactjs (frontend)
- Duende IdentityServer 6 for authentication

I hope this helps you out. Goodluck :)

Comment: Do you have a demo link or source code to demonstrate?

Comment: @UmarMalik Demo along with source code is available on Duende's github repo https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Samples/tree/main/IdentityServer/v6/BFF/ReactBffSample/src 
Unfortunately the solution I coded is confidential under organization's Non-Disclosure Agreement. But if you need more I will code a custom demo of my own and share in a day or two. Do let me know :)